# only clear part of full page cache

Tags: full-page-cache, redis, memcached

i'm using memcache and redis.  is it possible to clear only a certain page or group of pages using these?  Howso?  For example i'd like to be able to only clear the homepage instead of the entire FPC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the tags of the pages you can remove only those using

```
    $cache = Mage::app()->getCache();
    foreach($cache->getTags() as $tag){
        if(strpos($tag, 'my_cache_tag')){
            $ids = $cache->getIdsMatchingAnyTags(array($tag));
            foreach($ids as $id){
                $cache->remove($id);
            }
        }
    }
```

This can also be used to find out the keys you want to delete inspecting the content of the `$cache->getTags()` object. Source [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656933/how-to-get-magento-cache-refreshed-by-key)

[Here](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/developers-guide-magento-cache/) is a good guide for Magento cache management too.

Comment: does this work with FPC?

Comment: It should. Have you tried it?

Comment: how would one define or find a specific cache tag?

Comment: In the second link you will find out how to create cache with a tag and how to manipulate it once created. To find out a tag you will have to look into the core or maybe dump the content of $cache->getTags() object.